# What screw should I use for a ceiling fan?

Tags: ceiling-fan, screws

I am installing a ceiling fan in a newly built home. There's already a cover there and plate with wiring and two different types of screws in there. I wasn't sure which screws to use to hang up the fan.

I went with the smaller machine screws that are shown in the picture that are holding the fan up right now. I was just nervous because they were kind of small compared to the other longer ones I showed in the photo.

What is the correct one to use?

[image: one type of screw that was installed in the fixture box]

[image: second smaller type of screw that was installed in the fixture box]

Answer (score 3):

Generally the fan is supported by the electrical box.  These would be machine screws.  Wood screws would be used to hold the box to the structural part of the ceiling.

Comment: This, but it’s also extremely important that you use a fan-rated box, lest the whole thing come crashing down at the worst possible time.

Comment: Thanks. Is there some marking on the box to tell if it is rated for a fan?

Comment: Yes, @Scott, there should be. If you can provide a clear, focused pic, ask a whole new "Is this a fan rated box?" question and someone should be able to tell you. If it's not explicitly marked on the box, there might be a manufacturer's part number and someone could look it up from there.

Comment: Thanks I will do that.